# Defining set of a cyclic code

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, cryptography, coding-theory

I am asked to find a defining set of a binary cyclic code of length 15 which isn't a BCH code.

I already found the 2-cyclotomic cosets:

$C_0 = \{0\}$, $C_1 = \{1,2,4,8\}$, $C_3 = \{3,6,9,12\}$, $C_5 = \{5,10\}$, $C_7 = \{7,11,13,14\}$

but I am not sure how to get a definig set of a binary cyclic code of length 15. How can I find the defining set?

Comment: Often the defining set is the collection of the zeros of the generator polynomial. Possibly conjugate zeros can be omitted (often done when dealing with BCH-codes). You need to consult the textbook for the precise definition of *a defining set*. You get a BCH-code if the defining set consists of consecutive powers of a primitive element (together with all their conjugates, if that variant was adopted). So it seems natural to start by describing a primitive element $g$, and then list which of its powers are zeros of which factor.

Comment: Hmm. I now see that you are not required to give the generator polynomial. Then you can just play with cyclotomic cosets. $C_1$ gives a single-error correcting BCH-code, $C_1$ and $C_3$ together give a double-error-correcting code. But so do $C_7$ and $C_3$, if only for a different primitive element. Is the choice of primitive element given?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A primitive element is not given.